# locals().update(kwargs) is not working

Tags: python

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.bar(x=x)

    def bar(self, **kwargs):
        print kwargs
        locals().update(kwargs)
        print x


f = Foo(12)
```

this seems obvious, but it doesn't work, the first print would output `{'x': 12}`, which is correct, however, then I get this error: `NameError: global name 'x' is not defined`

Why would this happen? thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the [docs on `locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals): Note The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

Comment: Python does **not** have any *reliable* way of creating locals at runtime. Even `exec` wont work in many python versions (e.g. python3+ where `eval` is a function).

Answer (score 3):

The dictionary returned by [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) is read-only by contract. You cannot add variables dynamically to the current scope.